# How so I expand multi dimensional JSON in Power BI

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a number of JSON sources I wish to import to power BI. The format is such that foreign keys are such that there can be 0, 1, or many, but they store both the ID to another table as well as the name. An example of one entry in one of the JSON files is:

```
{
    "ID": "5bb68fde9088104f8c2a85be",
    "Name": "name here",
    "Date": "2018-10-04T00:00:00Z",
    "Account": {
      "ID": "5bb683509088104f8c2a85bc",
      "Name": "name here"
    },
    "Amount": 38.21,
    "Received": true
}
```

Some tables are much more complex etc, but for the most part, they always follow this sort of format for foreign keys. In power BI, I pull in the JSON, convert to table, and expand the column to view the top level in the table, but any lower levels, such as these foreign keys, are represented as lists. How do I pull them out into each row? I can extract values, but that duplicates rows etc.

I have googled multiple times for this and tried to follow what others have posted but can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: What do you expect your result to look like?

Comment: This post may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715592/how-can-i-turn-the-deepest-elements-of-nested-json-payload-into-individual-rows